# Print result in R console when passing variables to R script from Tableau to R

Tags: r, tableau-api, rserve

I am sending passing R scripts to R from Tableau and would like to be able to see the result in the R console.  I have got this to work in the past, but not sure how to do it again.

In R I've ran the following lines of code: 
Note, [Petal Length] is just a column of number values- it doesn't matter what the numbers are.  In this case I just got it from the IRIS dataset (which is pre-packaged in R as you can see if you run `data()`)

```
install.packages("Rserve") 
library(Rserve)
run.Rserve()
```

In Tableau, the calulated field that contains the R script is:

```
SCRIPT_INT('print(.arg1)', SUM([Petal length]))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching I finally found the answer to this question. 1) you have to have the function `print()` in the Tableau calculated field, and 2) you have to use the command: `run.Rserve()` as opposed to `Reserve()`.

Comment: does anybody know the difference between `run.Rserve()` and `Rserve()`? Thanks.

Comment: found the answer here: [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rserve/Rserve.pdf).  Apparently, "the main difference between Rserve and run.Rserve is
that Rserve starts a new process, whereas run.Rserve turns the current R session into Rserve."

Comment: you can accept your own answer to not leave it as unresolved